# AngularJS ui router $stateChangeStart with promise inifinite loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to build some sort of authentication in my angular app and would like to redirect to a external URL when a user is not logged in (based on a $http.get).

Somehow I end up in an infinite loop when the event.preventDefault() is the first line in the $stateChangeStart.

I've seen multiple issues with answers on stackoverflow, saying like *"place the event.preventDefault() just before the state.go in the else"*. But then the controllers are fired and the page is already shown before the promise is returned.

Even when I put the event.preventDefault() in the else, something odd happens:

Going to the root URL, it automatically adds the /#/ after the URL and $stateChangeStart is fired multiple times.

app.js run part:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$window', '$state', 'authentication', function ($rootScope, $window, $state, authentication) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams) {
        event.preventDefault();
        authentication.identity()
        .then(function (identity) {
             if (!authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
                 $window.location.href = 'external URL';
                 return;
            } else {
                 $state.go(toState, toParams);
            }
        });
    });
}]);
```

authentication.factory.js identity() function:

```
function getIdentity() {
    if (_identity) {
        _authenticated = true;
        deferred.resolve(_identity);
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    return $http.get('URL')
    .then(function (identity) { 
        _authenticated = true;
        _identity = identity;
        return _identity;
    }, function () {
        _authenticated = false;
    });
}
```

**EDIT**: Added the states:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('site', {
        url: '',
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            'feeds': {
                templateUrl: 'partials/feeds.html',
                controller: 'userFeedsController as userFeedsCtrl'
            }
        },
        resolve: ['$window', 'authentication', function ($window, authentication) {
            authentication.identity()
            .then(function (identity) {
                if (!authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
                    $window.location.href = 'external URL';
                }
            })
        }]
    })
    .state('site.start', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            'container@': {
                templateUrl: 'partials/start.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('site.itemList', {
        url: '/feed/{feedId}',
        views: {
            'container@': {
                templateUrl: 'partials/item-list.html',
                controller: 'itemListController as itemListCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('site.itemDetails', {
        url: '/items/{itemId}',
        views: {
            'container@': {
                templateUrl: 'partials/item-details.html',
                controller: 'itemsController as itemsCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
}])
```

If you need more info, or more pieces of code from the app.js let me know !

Comment: You already tried add the line: $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); In your route configuration. And add this metadata to html header: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">. This evict the uggly /# at the end of your URL.

Comment: Oh yeah i forgot that html5mode() record, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$stateChangeStart` will not wait for your promise to be resolved before exiting. The only way to make the state wait for a promise is to use `resolve` within the state's options.

```
.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    resolve: {
      auth: function($window, authentication) {
        return authentication.identity().then(function (identity) {
           if (!authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
             $window.location.href = 'external URL';
           }
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

By returning a promise from the function, ui-router won't initialize the state until that promise is resolved.

If you have other or children states that need to wait for this, you'll need to  inject `auth` in.

From the [wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views#inherited-resolved-dependencies):

> The resolve keys MUST be injected into the child states if you want to wait for the promises to be resolved before instantiating the children.

Comment: I have both actually. Because the resolve is only fired once (the first time the page is loaded). Or is there a way to make sure the resolve is always triggered ?

Comment: Yes, you could use the `reload` option of `$state.go()`. But that would be inefficient if you had other resolves because they would also be reloaded. http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state

Comment: Since you're caching the `_identity`, why would you want to trigger it every time?

Comment: I've added my states in the question.
I don't want the resolve to trigger every time, I want some kind of authentication check before any state is loaded. 

That's why I use the stateChangeStart, which is fired on every state change. When I debug, I can see that when the promise is returned, the state.go will be fired, so are you sure the stateChangeStart will not wait on the promise?

Comment: Yes, the code in your `then` block is executed. What I meant was that the state change will proceed regardless of the promise's state, which is why you're seeing your controllers firing before the promise resolves.

Comment: The question still remains though, since your factory is caching `_identity`, why do you need to check it after every state change? Wouldn't one check on the first page load be sufficient?

Comment: Hm good question. I cached it so my get wouldn't fire every state change.. I think I shouldn't cache it. I'll try that and will see if the infinite loop stays

Comment: Okay I've checked it, still the infinite loop even without caching.

I'm removing the statechangestart callback. Only check it on page load, like you said.

Thanks for the help and insights !